# Text is not in emulator is not showing, where it is in Graphic Layout

Tags: java, android, layout, hyperlink

In my graphic layout, I have a lot of text, with at the very end a hyperlink. Cause the text doesn't completely fit in my layout, I've added a scrollview. Now when I start my emulator, the only thing that gets shown is the hyperlink. No text at all.

This is what I see in my graphic layout before I run my project:
[image]

This is when I run my project:
[image]

Here is my Main activity code:

```
package com.example.rodekruis;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BWCActivity extends Activity {


     TextView HyperLink;
     Spanned Text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bwc);

        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/het_kinderbrandwondencentrum'> Kinderbrandwondencentrum </a>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

    }

}
```

And this is my activity_main code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Bezoek" >



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo" 
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"/>


    <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="364dp" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="276dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_bwc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />


</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only set the link in the TextView

```
String text = "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/het_kinderbrandwondencentrum'> Kinderbrandwondencentrum </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

If the text already contains the link use this:

```
String text = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_bwc);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Or if you want to add the link use this:

```
String text = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_bwc);
text += "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/het_kinderbrandwondencentrum'> Kinderbrandwondencentrum </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: I already have this code in my Main activity. Should this mean i have to remove the other 3 lines above it?

Comment: By using `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));` you delete the text that was set via `xml`

Comment: I've used the bottom one, now the text is shown, but the last word of the text, which is: Kinderbrandwondencentrum, isn't a hyperlink, it's just a normal word.

Comment: It is working on my emulator. Note: you still have to use `Html.fromHtml(text)` also check the text in `R.string.title_activity_bwc` maybe there are some html tags that aren't closed properly.

Comment: But you just said that that html.fromhtml(text) part deletes the text from xml? Could you type that line out?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The method you are using, `setText` was removing the the text that was placed via `xml`, not the `Html.fromHtml(text)`. First get the text via `getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_bwc);` then add your link `text += "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/het_kinderbrandwondencentrum'> Kinderbrandwondencentrum </a>";` and after that set it to the `TextView` via `setText` like this `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));`

Comment: oh one second, I haven't used html tags in my xml file yet. Do I have to put this: <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/het_kinderbrandwondencentrum'> Kinderbrandwondencentrum </a> 
instead of the word that I want the link to be in?

Comment: Yes, you can place also the link `<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/het_kinderbrandwondencentrum'> Kinderbrandwondencentrum </a>` inside your xml file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110236/discussion-between-koen-hilarius-and-exaqt).

Comment: Are you still here? I found another problem, it is somehow fixed, but now all the enters, used from \n\n are dissapeared, and the links are only at the very end of the text. When in another activity i want to make an hyperlink in the middle of the text, it automatically gets to the end. Can you help me with this as well?